Flutter Riverpod function not updating data instantly
i created a simple function that add product to cart with buttons to add/reduce product quantity,unfortunately product quantity does not changes as add/reduce button is hit.it changes after some refresh.also the product is not added to cart.please help me identify the problem
These are codes.
productmodel class
    class ProductModel {
  int? id;
  int qty=1;
  String? product_name;
  String? product_description;
  int? product_price;
  String? images;

  ProductModel({this.id,required this.qty, this.product_name, this.product_description, this.product_price, this.images});

  ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = int.tryParse(json['id']);
    product_name = json['product_name'];
    product_description = json['product_description'];
    product_price = int.tryParse(json['product_price']);
    images = json['images'];
    qty=json[1]??1;
  }
}

this is StateNotifier class
    import 'package:five_star/ProductModel.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class Productstore extends StateNotifier<List<ProductModel>>{
  Productstore(): super([]);
  List<ProductModel> _carts=[];
  List<ProductModel> get carts=> _carts;

  void addToCart(ProductModel product) {
    if (carts.contains(product)) {
      product.qty++;
    } else {
      carts.add(product);
    }
  }

  void removeFromCart(ProductModel product) {

      carts.remove(product);
  }
  void removeCartqty(ProductModel product) {
    if (product.qty == 1) {
      carts.remove(product);
    } else if (product.qty > 1) {
      product.qty--;
    }
  }

  void addCartqty(ProductModel product) {
      product.qty++;

  }


}

This is product detail class where i call addtocart function with functions to +/- product quantity.
import 'package:five_star/Cart.dart';
import 'package:five_star/ProductModel.dart';
import 'package:five_star/ProductStore.dart';
import 'package:five_star/all_products.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:five_star/home.dart';
final cartprovider=StateNotifierProvider<Productstore,List<ProductModel>>((ref)=>Productstore());
class product_detail extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const product_detail({super.key});

  @override
  product_detailState createState() => product_detailState();
}
class product_detailState extends ConsumerState<product_detail> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final product = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as ProductModel;
    final cartnotifier=ref.watch(cartprovider.notifier);
    final cartNotifier = ref.read(cartprovider.notifier);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('PRODUCT DETAIL'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding:  EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 160,
                    width: double.infinity,
                  child: (
                  Card(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Image.network("https://hometronix.co.tz/admin/images/products/"+product.images.toString()),
                  )

                  ),
                        //BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                  ),

                ),
                 Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text(
                        product.product_name.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                 Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                    child: Text(
                      product.product_price.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding:  EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 200,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration:  BoxDecoration(),
                    child:  Center(
                        child: Text( product.product_description.toString())),
                  ),
                ),

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              cartNotifier.removeCartqty(product);

                            },
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.remove,
                              color: Colors.red,
                            )),
                        Text(
                          product.qty.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              cartNotifier.addCartqty(product);
                            },
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.add,
                              color: Colors.green,
                            )),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        cartNotifier.addToCart(product);
                      },
                      child: const Text(
                        'add to cart',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


You should use ref.watch(cartprovider); instead of using ref.watch(cartprovider.notifier);

There are several problems with the class Productstore. The state of the StateNotifier<List<ProductModel>> is stored in the super constructor and it makes no sense to have the list:
List<ProductModel> _carts=[];

Instead you should have something similar to:
void addToCart(ProductModel product) {
  if (state.contains(product)) {
      product.qty++;
  } else {
      // The UI is only updated if a new state is created. 
      // Just adding an element will not trigger a rebuild. *) 
      state = [...state, product];
  }
}

*) See riverpod documentation regarding StateNotifier.
Like choykarl mentioned, you are supposed to watch cartprovider instead of its notifier.
Lastly, the documentation recommends migrating from StateNotifier to NotifierProvider see migration from StateNotifier.

I fixed your code, it compiles, but I did not understand where you use your list of products in the widget. Anyway, if you change it, it should rebuild all.
Here the code (I used riverpod and freezed from the same author):
This is the Model:
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'product_model.freezed.dart';

@freezed
class ProductModel with _$ProductModel {
  factory ProductModel({
    int? id,
    @Default(1) int qty,
    String? productName,
    String? productDescription,
    int? productPrice,
    String? images,
  }) = _ProductModel;
}

Now this is the Notifier:
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';

import 'product_model.dart';

part 'state_notifier.g.dart';

@riverpod
class StateNotifier extends _$StateNotifier {
  @override
  List<ProductModel> build() => List.empty();

  ProductModel addToCart(ProductModel product) {
    final result = product.copyWith(
        qty: state.contains(product) ? product.qty + 1 : product.qty);

    if (!state.contains(product)) {
      state = [...state, product];
    }
    return result;
  }

  void removeFromCart(ProductModel product) {
    state = [...state]..remove(product);
  }

  ProductModel removeCartqty(ProductModel product) {
    final result =
        product.copyWith(qty: product.qty > 1 ? product.qty - 1 :     product.qty);

    if (product.qty == 1) {
      state = [...state]..remove(product);
    }
    return result;
  }

  ProductModel addCartqty(ProductModel product) =>
      product.copyWith(qty: product.qty + 1);
}

Now, there is your widget, note that it will be updated every time you add/remove items from the state, but pay attention because the state is never displayed. Should you add an other widget???
The view is updated thanks to the .watch(...) call.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:five_star/product_model.dart';
import 'package:five_star/state_notifier.dart';

class ProductDetails extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const ProductDetails({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ProductDetails> createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends ConsumerState<ProductDetails> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final product = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as ProductModel;
final myState = ref.watch(stateNotifierProvider);
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('PRODUCT DETAIL'),
    backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
  ),
  body: ListView(
    children: [
      Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 160,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: (Card(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Image.network(
                      "https://hometronix.co.tz/admin/images/products/${product.images}"),
                )),
                //BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  child: Text(
                    product.productName ?? '',
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                child: Text(
                  (product.productPrice ?? 0).toString(),
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(),
                child:
                    Center(child: Text(product.productDescription ?? '')),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          ref
                              .read(stateNotifierProvider.notifier)
                              .removeCartqty(product);
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.remove,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        )),
                    Text(
                      product.qty.toString(),
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          ref
                              .read(stateNotifierProvider.notifier)
                              .addCartqty(product);
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.add,
                          color: Colors.green,
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                    foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    ref
                        .read(stateNotifierProvider.notifier)
                        .addToCart(product);
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    'add to cart',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
    );
  }
}

I hope to be useful.
Some hints:

the model should be immutable, thus don't change it, create a new one (as I made in the Notifier);
The state notifier should be declared as specified in the riverpod documentations (use annotations)
The name conventions are important: the class name should be CamelCase, while the file name should be camel_case.dart

